# How can I paginate list of dictionaries in django

Tags: django, pagination

I am working on Django pagination and trying to paginate my data which is in the form of dictionaries inside a list, I tried function based approach as per documentation

```
class MyUserData(TemplateView):
template_name = "myuserdata.html"
form = "userform"

def listing(request):
    contact_list = Contact.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 25) # Show 25 contacts per page.

    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    return render(request, 'list.html', {'page_obj': page_obj})
```

I am writing above function inside my class which is inheriting (TemplateView) now the problem is that it is reducing the number of results to 25 but when i click on next it doesn't show next page

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

Flow is like this the user will come and enter the start date and end date and click on submit and get's his history of data and the issue is user gets all his history if he selects longer date range which I want to paginate

this is how data is coming in the form of dictionaries inside list

[{'date':'2021/12/02','address':'minneapolis 111 NY','machine':'TR'},{'date':'2021/12/03','address':'minneapolis 111 NY','machine':'MR'},{'date':'2021/12/02','address':'minneapolis 111 NY','machine':'PR'},{'date':'2021/12/02','address':'minneapolis 111 NY','machine':'CR'},{'date':'2021/12/12','address':'minneapolis 111 NY','machine':'RR'}]

This data is coming from api and not from django models.

I tried function based approach inside class which inherits the template view
is it possible that I can try this inside class, as per documentation if I am writing class I need to use ListView is it possible in Templateview?  i have to use ListView only?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of dictionaries in a variable `data`:

```py
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

paginator = Paginator(data, 3)
# 3 here is limit number, you can give dynamic value changing it to your required limit number

objects = paginator.page(1)
# 1 here is page number, you can give dynamic value changing it to your required page number

print(list(objects))
# This should print first 3 data as a list
```

Comment: objects = paginator.page(1),
here I have mentioned page number 1 but suppose it have 100 pages so how will I go to next page , how can I make it dynamic
u mean like this page_number = request.GET.get('page') ?
i tried this but doesn't gets me to next page